# How to create hash with automatically generated ranges in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, range, iteration

I want to create a simple timer, that start from 0, has_many points and stop working when i push stop button.

```
Timer.start == 0
Timer.point = Time.now
Timer.fin = Time.now
```

I would like to create a timeline hash  with ranges for every points in seconds.
Something looks like Timeline.new(timer.point.first[0..4], timer.point.second[5..11] ... timer.point.last [42..56])

I think I should use an iteration, but have no idea how setup point[from..till] arguments. Sorry, don't have much practice.
Any solutions, ideas? 
TY4HLP

Comment: Really hard to understand what you´re asking here and the code you provided does not make much sense.

Comment: this looks like homework...is it ? Also please explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve, I've been reading this question for five minutes now and still cannot understand it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [while loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) for your task